# (MVVM/WPF) Manipulating View Elements in View-Model

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, mvvm

I have a **ListView** with some *Images* on it that I want to works like this:
[image]

I did that using **Command** and **CommandParameter** for sending **ListView** to my **View-Model** and then manipulating *width* and *height* of each image:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding MVM.SelectedChangedCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=listView}"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

**ViewModel:**

```
private void SelectedChangedAction(object param)    
{
    ListView s = (ListView)param;

    double j = 1;
    for (int i = s.SelectedIndex - 1; i >= 0 && j >= 0; i--, j -= 0.15)
    {
        Pic t = (Pic)s.Items[i];
        t.Width = 150 * j;
        t.Height = 250 * j;
    }


    j = 1;
    for (int i = s.SelectedIndex + 1; i < s.Items.Count && j >= 0; i++, j -= 0.15)
    {
        Pic t = (Pic)s.Items[i];
        t.Width = 150 * j;
        t.Height = 250 * j;
    }
    s.ScrollIntoView(s.Items[s.SelectedIndex]);
}
```

But as I said and you can see in **View-Model**, I used **ListView** in **VM** and I think that's a violation! So how can I do something like this in **MVVM**?
(Of course I think I can build a new controller based on ListView that could do that, though I need a simple solution like XAML or something)

Comment: Manipulating the image sizes in your control is a function of the UI, so you are perfectly fine just creating a UserControl and performing all your layout manipulations in there.

Comment: @Will That's right. But as Nikhil said, How can I do that without Converters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a property for SelectedItem in ViewModel. Bind it in View's ListView. Set Bind Height and Width with a converter and move all your logic there.

Comment: Actually I'm using this right now, But that just works for the Selected Item. How can I change other items width and height based on their indexes?

Comment: You can pass whole ListView in converter.

Comment: Works great. Thanks! But I want to know, In **Converter** there is know limitation for using **Views** and **Models**?

Comment: You cannot access View in VM. In Converters or Behaviours, you can use them.

Answer (score 1):

Although you've accepted a solution, I found the question interesting so I found the following solution:

**XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="SO40564064.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SO40564064"        
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="500" Width="600">
    <Grid>
    <ListView Name="TheView" ItemsSource="{Binding Images}">
      <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <local:MyImageBorder Width="{Binding Width}" 
                  Height="{Binding Height}"
                  Background="{Binding Color}"
                  IsMouseOverMe="{Binding MouseIsOverMe, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        </DataTemplate>
      </ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
          <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"></StackPanel>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
      </ListView.ItemsPanel>
    </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Code Behind:**

```
namespace SO40564064
{
  /// <summary>
  /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
  /// </summary>
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
  {
    public MainWindow()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
      DataContext = new ViewModel();
    }    
  }
}
```

**ViewModel:**

```
  public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
  {
    public ViewModel()
    {
      m_images = new ObservableCollection<MyImage>(
        new MyImage[] {
          new MyImage() { Color = Brushes.Red, Height = 100, Width = 70 },
          new MyImage() { Color = Brushes.Green, Height = 100, Width = 70 },
          new MyImage() { Color = Brushes.Blue, Height = 100, Width = 70 },
          new MyImage() { Color = Brushes.Yellow, Height = 100, Width = 70 },
          new MyImage() { Color = Brushes.Magenta, Height = 100, Width = 70 },
          new MyImage() { Color = Brushes.Cyan, Height = 100, Width = 70 }
          });

      foreach (var image in m_images)
      {
        image.PropertyChanged += Image_PropertyChanged;
      }
    }

    private void Image_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
      switch (e.PropertyName)
      {
        case "MouseIsOverMe":

          var curImage = sender as MyImage;
          var curIndex = m_images.IndexOf(curImage);

          if (curImage.MouseIsOverMe)
          {
            if (curIndex > 0)
            {
              m_images[curIndex - 1].Width *= 1.2;
              m_images[curIndex - 1].Height *= 1.2;
            }
            if (curIndex < m_images.Count - 2)
            {
              m_images[curIndex + 1].Width *= 1.2;
              m_images[curIndex + 1].Height *= 1.2;
            }

            m_images[curIndex].Width *= 1.5;
            m_images[curIndex].Height *= 1.5;
          }
          else
          {
            if (curIndex > 0)
            {
              m_images[curIndex - 1].Width /= 1.2;
              m_images[curIndex - 1].Height /= 1.2;
            }
            if (curIndex < m_images.Count - 2)
            {
              m_images[curIndex + 1].Width /= 1.2;
              m_images[curIndex + 1].Height /= 1.2;
            }

            m_images[curIndex].Width /= 1.5;
            m_images[curIndex].Height /= 1.5;
          }
          break;
        default:
          break;
      }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<MyImage> m_images;
    public ObservableCollection<MyImage> Images
    {
      get { return m_images; }
      set
      {
        m_images = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Images");
      }
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string property)
    {
      PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
    }
  }
```

**Image ViewModel class:**

```
  public class MyImage : INotifyPropertyChanged
  {
    private double m_width;
    public double Width
    {
      get { return m_width; }
      set
      {
        m_width = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Width");
      }
    }

    private double m_height;
    public double Height
    {
      get { return m_height; }
      set
      {
        m_height = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Height");
      }
    }

    private Brush m_color;
    public Brush Color
    {
      get { return m_color; }
      set
      {
        m_color = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Color");
      }
    }

    private bool m_mouseIsOverMe;
    public bool MouseIsOverMe
    {
      get { return m_mouseIsOverMe; }
      set
      {
        m_mouseIsOverMe = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("MouseIsOverMe");
      }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string property)
    {
      PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
    }
  }
```

**"Image" Control Subclass (here a Border subclass):**

```
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace SO40564064
{
  public class MyImageBorder : Border
  {
    public MyImageBorder()
    {
      IsMouseDirectlyOverChanged += MyImageBorder_IsMouseDirectlyOverChanged;
    }

    public bool IsMouseOverMe
    {
      get { return (bool)GetValue(IsMouseOverMeProperty); }
      set { SetValue(IsMouseOverMeProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsMouseOverMeProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("IsMouseOverMe", typeof(bool), typeof(MyImageBorder), new PropertyMetadata(false));

    private void MyImageBorder_IsMouseDirectlyOverChanged(object sender, System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
      IsMouseOverMe = (bool)e.NewValue;
    }
  }
}
```

For my own convenience I've subclassed a Border where you might subclass an Image (or something you can wrap an image in).

The solution works when the mouse hovers over each image - not when an image is selected. You can style the ugly default border of the hovered element away in a custom style.

Answer (score 0):

You really shouldn't be directly manipulating view components in your view model. Instead, this mechanism should be achieved by writing a custom layout panel that performs the sizing of elements in the view. [This page](http://drwpf.com/blog/category/panels/) has some good information on how to achieve this.

Comment: I looked at the first image, And I saw they just work on SelectedItem. But I want to work on all of the items based on their indexes. They do that too?